# Display a different sentences each time user visites a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

A thought would be to have different welcome message displayed each time user visites a page, like: 
First visit -
*Welcome*

Second visit -
*Hi again*

Next visit and forever after -
*no message*

Can anyone tell me how would I would be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Of course, you can accomplish this. What have you tried so far? Show us your effort and tell us where you needed help. Pls be aware that `SO` is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of using [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) on the client side,
Cookies can be created with javascript or even with server side languages.
An example of storing user information on cookie using javascript would be like,

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method to create a cookie with PHP. This cookie will expire after 30 days.

```
$value = 'something from somewhere';

setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

So using cookies you can track the user visits, you could fetch a different welcome message from the db, each time a user visit your site.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time user visits the page, put a value to session.

when he comes back check if the session value exists, then show "Hi again" message, and set another value in session.

check if the value exists show "no message".

```
    if(session value for first visit exist) {
       show "Hi again" message
    }
    else if(session value for second visit exist) {

    }
    else {
      show welcome message
    }
```